# adding comment system in joomla 1.6 articles

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.6

How can I add user comment system in joomla 1.6 articles? Its for a custom blog system. there is a article category named "Blog" in the site. I want, when user read articles of this category, they can comment on it. there are some extensions for joomla 1.5. but cannot find any good one for 1.6. i also found "discussit" for discussion. but don't like it much to use 3rd party. it would better to use a pure commenting system for a article category. you can also suggest a free blog extension for joomla 1.6. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not free but you could integrate Facebook commenting with this extension -

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/facebook-integration/7215#rev-92243

If FB is prevalent in your area this could be a very good solution since it has the added advantage of other FB users seeing your comments.

Otherwise, did you look st JA Comment. It's probably your best bet as a pure commenting system.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/articles-comments/12078

At this point, your only other choice will be to upgrade to one of the CCK systems that has commenting built in.

Answer (score 0):

Yootheme (Professional Joomla Club) has also a solution as part of their Joomla Appication Framwork Zoo (http://www.yootheme.com/zoo/index.php). 
Take a look here http://www.yootheme.com/zoo/app-bundle/blog/frontpage.

Rockettheme (The other big one in the market) has a comment system : 
http://www.rockettheme.com/extensions-joomla/rokcomments